Extension of time homogeneous short rate model in Brigo Mercurio
Question
I am going through section 3.8 "A General Deterministic Drift Extension" in Brigo Mercurio, and in particular section 3.8.4 "The Vasicek Case". I want to derive the equation for $\varphi^{VAS}$.



$\varphi^{VAS}$ is defined as follows (page 98):
\begin{align*}
     \varphi^{VAS} &= f^M(0,t) - f^x(0,t;\alpha) \\
                   &= f^M(0,t) + \frac{\partial \ln P^x (0,t)}{\partial t}
\end{align*}
Comparing the definition with the expression I want to derive, we can see that one only needs to compute $\frac{\partial \ln P^x (0,t)}{\partial t}$.  Could you tell me if my approach is correct or whether there is a simpler way? If there is no easier way, how can I solve the component with the double integral?
My attempt
The process for the short rate in the Vasicek model is:
\begin{align*}
        dx_t^\alpha &= k [\theta - x_t^\alpha] dt + \sigma dW_t
\end{align*}
Integrating:
\begin{align*}
        x_t^\alpha &= x_s^\alpha e^{-k (t-s)} + \theta \left( 1 - e^{-k (t-s)} \right) + \sigma \int_s^t e^{-k (t-u)} dW_u
\end{align*}
Finally, I compute $\frac{\partial \ln P^x(0,t)}{\partial t}$:
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\partial \ln P^x(0,t)}{\partial t} \\
        &= \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \ln E^x \left\{ \exp \left[ - \int_0^t x^\alpha_s ds \right] \right\} \\
        &= \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \ln E^x \left\{ \exp \left[ - \int_0^t \left( x_0^\alpha e^{-k s} + \theta \left( 1 - e^{-k s} \right) + \sigma \int_0^s e^{-k (s-u)} dW_u \right) ds \right] \right\} \\
        &= \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \ln E^x \left\{ \exp \left[ - \int_0^t x_0^\alpha e^{-k s} ds - \theta \int_0^t \left( 1 - e^{-k s} \right) ds - \sigma \int_0^t \int_0^s e^{-k (s-u)} dW_u ds \right] \right\} \\
        &= \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \ln E^x \left\{ \exp \left[ \frac{x_0^\alpha}{k} \left( e^{-k t} - 1 \right)  - \theta \left( t + \frac{e^{-k t} - 1}{k} \right) - \sigma \int_0^t \int_0^s e^{-k (s-u)} dW_u ds \right] \right\} \\
        &= \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left[ \frac{x_0^\alpha}{k} \left( e^{-k t} - 1 \right)  - \theta \left( t + \frac{e^{-k t} - 1}{k} \right) \right] + \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \ln E^x \left\{ \exp \left[ - \sigma \int_0^t \int_0^s e^{-k (s-u)} dW_u ds \right] \right\} \\
        &= - x_0^\alpha e^{-k t} - \theta \left( 1 - e^{-k t} \right) + \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \ln E^x \left\{ \exp \left[ - \sigma \int_0^t \int_0^s e^{-k (s-u)} dW_u ds \right] \right\}
\end{align*}
